# How to find the nearest midnights

Tags: python, datetime

I have times which are in the form of seconds since the start of the Unix epoch. For example, 1410974864 which is Wed, 17 Sep 2014 17:27:44 GMT .

How can I find the start and end of the day  for a given time in this form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datetime` and `pytz` are a good team for that:

```
   import datetime, pytz

   epoch = 1410974864
   dt_epoch = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch, tz=pytz.UTC)
   dt_midnight = dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

So, the beginning and end of day:

```
   day_start = dt_midnight
   day_end = dt_midnight + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that a day is 3600 seconds/hour * 24 hours = 86400 seconds. So just take the time you have and mod it by 86400:

```
seconds_through_current_day = current_time % 86400
```

Now you have how many seconds have elapsed since the beginning of the day so subtract this from the total time since epoch and you'll be left with the beginning of the current day

```
beginning_of_current_day = current_time - second_through_current_day
```

Lastly, just add a day's worth of seconds to get the end of the current day

```
end_of_current_day = beginning_of_current_day + 86400
```